# Named Credentials: How to Start OAuth flow?

Tags: apex, authentication, oauth, namedcredentials

I'm using Named Credentials with OAuth authentication. When calling a method on the endpoint, my Apex app receives back the status that the token needs to be refreshed.

How do I tell Salesforce to start the OAuth process for my Named Credential?

**Added**

Everything is setup and works fine:

- The external SAAS service uses OAuth Authorization Code Grant with its own OAuth endpoints.
- Created Authentication Metadata in SFDC for the service
- Wrote and installed an Auth Provider Plugin Apex class
- Authorized the Remote Site for just the authorization service (not for the API url itself.)
- Added the new Auth Provider
- Added the new Named Credential

Next

- Each user then adds an entry for the Auth Provider via their Personal Settings / Authentication Settings for External Systems screen.
- Completing this step causes the OAuth process to happen: the browser is redirected to the SAAS service's authentication service. After authenticating and authorizing the app, the person is returned to SFDC.
- At this point, the person can use the Apex application which makes use of the Named Credential.
- Life is good.

**However,** 8 hours later, the token needs to be refreshed.

The best would be for my Apex program to be able to rerun the OAuth flow. The user would then re-login, as needed.

So back to the original question: How do I tell Salesforce to start the OAuth process for my Named Credential or for the user's Authentication Settings for External Systems record?

**Currently,** if my Apex program detects that the user needs to re-authenticate, I give them the following instructions. What I want is to give the user a button that they push. That would cause the OAuth flow to start.

> - From My Settings, enter auth in the Quick Find box, then select 
>     **Authentication Settings for External Systems**
> - For the -saas service- entry, click **Edit** then click **Save**. 
>     Depending on your -saas service- security settings, you may be redirected to the -saas service- to sign in.
>     [More information.](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=external_authentication.htm&siteLang=en_US)

Comment: Can you add some more details to your questions for ex. code spinet, the end point, any configuration that you have done on end point. I will help us to diagnose the issue. Id possible add details to such a level where we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Named Credentials generally works fine and probability there must be configuration issue causing this problem.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 Everything is working fine until the user needs to re-authenticate with the remote system. How can my Apex program initiate the flow so the user doesn't have to click through their settings themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are authenticated you don't need to re-authenticate with external service again.

Every external system provide refresh token with `access token` and using that `refresh token` you need to refresh the access token.

You can use batch which will run in backend and refresh your access token. Schedule this batch to run in 7 hours.

To refresh the `access token` using `refresh token` you can follow these links.

1. [OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token Flow](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm)

Although this is link for SF token but the basic idea will remain same here.

Sample code.

```
POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.salesforce.com/ 
grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=Your client id here&client_secret=Your client secert here
&refresh_token=your token here
```

For the second point where you need to re-authentication you can do one thing. Create a checkbox and if checkbox is true then update record type with a button for re-authentication and once user click on this button and re-authenticate you can again change the `pagelayout` and hide the button.

In your batch if you get time 0 then update the record with checkbox true.so user can see the button for re-authenticate.

And as you are system admin so you need to store their access token and refresh token in some place and your code can access it from there.

Comment: Sorry @TusharSharma, you are not correct. Some higher security SAAS services do require periodic re-authentication by the user. (Token refreshes can give a 0 validity time if that is their security policy.) Also, you're not providing any information on how to refresh the tokens of the individual users. I don't see how I have any access to the app's client id or secret, either. Only the Named Credential system has access to that info.

Comment: @LarryK updated my answer. Please check.